# Преобразовать время в нужный формат

Tags: python, datetime

Как преобразовать время, которое я получаю в переменную sunrise_form (15:9), в 15:09?

```
sunset = sunsets.sunset_time('iso')
                    sunset_format = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(sunset)

                    sunrise = sunsets.sunrise_time('iso')
                    sunsire_format = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(sunrise)
                    sunsire_format.strftime("%hh:%mm")
                    sunsire_format.date()
                    result = w.weather
                    windy = weather.wind()

                    wis = weather.visibility_distance
                    clouds = weather.clouds
                    temperature = Label(tk,
                                        text=f'Погода в городе {str(inputs["text"])} на завтра'
                                             f'{str("-") + str(result.detailed_status)}\n'
                                             f'Погода ощущается как {round(number=feels_like)}°С  \n'
                                             f'Максимальная температура {round(number=max_temp)}°С \n'
                                             f'Минимальная температура {round(number=min_temp)}°С  \n'
                                             f'Температура прямо сейчас {round(number=cel["temp"])}°С\n'
                                             f'Влажность-{round(number=humidity)} %\n'
                                             f'Скорость ветра-{round(number=windy["speed"])}м/с  \n'
                                             f'Количество облаков-{round(number=clouds)}%\n'
                                             f'Средний статистический показатель погоды за '
                                             f' {datetime.datetime.today().month}'
                                             f'.{datetime.datetime.now().day + 1} число- {round(number=feels_like)} °С\n'
                                             f'Видимость {round(number=wis / 1000)}'
                                             f'км,Давление {ceil(ref / 1.33245033213)} '
                                             f'мм.рт.ст,Закат начинается в {sunset_format.hour}:{sunset_format.minute},'
                                             f'Рассвет {sunsire_format.hour}:{sunsire_format.minute}'

                                        , fg='gold', bg='SteelBlue4', width=200, height=10, foreground='gold',
                                        borderwidth=2, activeforeground='SteelBlue', font=("Arial Bold", 17),
                                        justify='center')
                    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: где вас учать писать "вопрос заключается в том"?? Ну и минус за кривое оформление https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `sunsire_format.strftime("%hh:%mm")` наверняка делает то, что вам надо. просто выводите его, а не используйте отдельно часы и минуты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно преобразовать одной строкой

```
'{:02}:{:02}'.format(*map(int, t.strip(')(').split(':')))`
```

Демо:

```
times = ['(15:9)', '(5:9)', '(15:19)']

for t in times:
    ftime = '{:02}:{:02}'.format(*map(int, t.strip(')(').split(':')))
    print(ftime)
```

```
15:09
05:09
15:19
```

Comment: спасибо! Все работает!

Answer (score 0):

Можете реализовать свою функцию преобразования времени. Например так:

```py
def convert(t):
    t = t.strip('(').strip(')')
    hours, minutes = t.split(':')
    return f'{hours.rjust(2, "0")}:{minutes.rjust(2, "0")}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(convert('(15:9)'))
    print(convert('(7:44)'))
    print(convert('(13:22)'))
```